# Excel does not honor the delimiter setting for reading or writing CSV files

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel, csv, regional-settings

When saving/opening CSV files in Excel, the default separator is a semicolon `;`, as I need it to be a comma `,` I tried to change it by changing the Language and Regional settings following several other posts about this issue (i.e. [How to get Excel to interpret the comma as a default delimiter in CSV files?](https://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files)).

However, after changing the List separator in those settings, my Excel keeps saving CSV files with a semicolon. Is it because Excel was installed while my list separator was set as a semicolon? or is there another setting I am missing here?

Comment: Is the problem in reading existing CSV files or creating one using comma as the delimiter?

Comment: Both, I have already done what @Raystafarian mentioned before saving a new file. My regional setting is correct. Then I open Excel and save as CSV and when I open the file in notepad I can see that it used a semicolon. If I open in Excel it does load correctly because Excel still uses a ; for separating the columns.

Answer (score 37):

I found the problem. My decimal symbol in the Regional settings was also a comma (European) so, even when my List separator was a comma, the CSV was saved with semicolons. Now I changed my decimal symbol to a point and now the CSV file is created correctly with commas as separators. I tested this twice and now know that there must be an exception: if the decimal symbol is a comma, then the list separator will be a semicolon even is set otherwise.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to update the post with an answer.

Answer (score 5):

### For saving

You need to adjust the list separator in language and regional settings *prior* to saving the file -

[image]

---

### For opening

Go to **Data - Get External Data - From Text**

[image]

select the file

Select **delimited**, press next
[image]

and select the **delimiter** *comma*

[image]

Click finish

[image]

---

Or, pull it in and then use text to columns [see here](https://superuser.com/questions/407082/easiest-way-to-open-csv-with-commas-in-excel/407085#407085)

Comment: If I read the question right, it looks like the problem is creating (saving), a delimited file using commas for the delimiter (2nd paragraph).

Comment: @fixer1234 yeah that's how I read it at first. But then I thought the first paragraph was the important one. I've no idea which is correct. Either way, I have no solution for the creation other than what the OP mentioned they've already tried.

Comment: Yes, I did change the regional settings before saving the file. It didn't help. When I receive CSV files from other people which are delimited with a comma, then I use your method for importing the data correctly, then I save and it goes to a semicolon. It's annoying because every time I need to go to notepad and replace all semicolons with commas before using my CSV as an import file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very nice macro that works quite well:

```
Sub saveCSV()
File = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="file.csv", FileFilter:="CSV (*.csv), *.csv")
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=File, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, local:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit old, but I ran into the same problem:
Had a CSV delimited with semicolon (`;`). System separator settings (Windows) also set to semicolon.

- If I opened the CSV manually, the file was separated correctly.
- If I let VBA open it, it separated it incorrectly with a comma.

Using `Delimiter:=";"` apparently only works with `.txt`.

HOWEVER, using `Local :=True` solved the problem for me:

```
Workbooks.Open(Filename:=fullpath, Local:=True)
```