# Create CSV file from Excel with delimiter other than comma?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, csv

Is there a way to create a CSV file from an Excel one, but with a delimiter other than comma?

I tried changing Windows parameters. In Windows Control Panel -> Click, Language & Region -> formats parameters panel, I set the delimiter I wanted and then created the CSV file. That didn't work.

Specifically, I'm looking for a way to force the French version (Excel 2007) to export CSV with comma delimiter instead of semicolon.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Excel does not honor the delimiter setting for reading or writing CSV files](http://superuser.com/questions/832786/excel-does-not-honor-the-delimiter-setting-for-reading-or-writing-csv-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List separator set in `Language & Region` settings will not work if you have Decimal Separator set to same character.

So if you have `,` set as decimal separator set there - you cannot have `,` as list separator and Excel will use default `;`.

You have to use `.` as decimal separator or write some macro that will save your document in desired format.

Comment: I need the decimal separator to stay comma, because there are some decimals in the CSV. So ideally, I need the CSV to be generated with a comma delimiter and with all columns being surrounded by " " (to escape the decimals separator which is comma). I believe a macro is the quickest way to do this. The problem is: I've never created a macro before ... ;)

Comment: @yo_haha So you need a macro that will build whole CSV content.

Comment: @yo_haha If you don't want to mess up with macros - maybe save your file with default settings and modify it by some external tool (there are many CSV converters).

Comment: I'll try CSV converters before the macros :) Thanks

Comment: Do you've got in mind the name of some converter that allows delimiter changing?

Comment: Nope. It might be good idea for another question.

Comment: I found a very nice macro that works `Sub saveCSV()
    File = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:="file.csv", FileFilter:="CSV (*.csv), *.csv")
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=File, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, local:=False
End Sub`