# How to change default csv separator in Excel 2013?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm trying to export my `XLSX` file to `CSV` using Excel 2013.
The problem I am facing is that the resulting CSV file uses `semicolon (;)` as a separator. I need it to be a `comma (,)`.
I've changed my regional settings to use comma as a list separator:

[image]

However, Excel still exports with semicolon. How to make it export csv with comma as a separator?

Comment: Try changing the Decimal symbol from `,` to `.` as well.

Comment: ... and then the thousands grouping from `.` to " " (space). *Yes, it is as horrible as this* - I'm not sure this helps though. It might be easier to load the file into wordpad or notepad and replace `;` to `,` .

Comment: there's always an option to do post-processing.. but being that I'm often in the need to export csv, it would be useful to know how to do this in Excel directly

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you've spotted, the list separator isn't for CSV.

I guess this is because you are using comma as the decimal so the default for "comma" separated files becomes semi-colon separated.

I think the only native solution is to change back to standard english settings before saving the file.

Or, as mentioned above, use a utility to change the `;` to `,` post save. You could even get clever and intercept the save process in VBA (or simply create your own save button) to output the csv and then call out to the filing system libraries to do a replace text on the file.

Comment: I confirm this works. @srgb you should mark this as the correct answer.