# How to make excel open CSV files and automatically split the comma delimited column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, csv

I get these reports everyday in CSV format. In the previous version of excel (2007) when I opened these files they were already split into columns. Now with the latest version it isn't. Where is this setting I'm missing?

Thanks in advance.

Erin

Comment: You can do this by selecting Data ---> Text to columns

Comment: I know. I want it to be automatic like in version 2007. When I open it, it should already be split.

Comment: There is about a 90 % of the issue with your source data.  Open notepad or some other editor you like, make a .txt file with 3 or 4 rows and columns of data. Each row should have the same number of commas. Then after saved, change the extension to .csv then open with Excel. Do you still get the data in all in the A column?

Comment: I did that and I found its because this excel recognizes ";" instead of the ","  - formulas as well. How can I change it to ","?

Comment: See https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/change-excel-csv-delimiter/

Answer (score 7):

Here are some easy explanations on how to do it **automatically** when you open your file with Excel:

As you said, Excel has a default character as a delimiter. In your case, this is ";" visibly. I am working on Excel in France and the default delimiter is "[tab]".

I don't know how to change it in the software but there is a trick:
For example, let's say that your .csv file is **delimited with ";"** and you want that Excel interpret it automatically, simply add on the first line of your .csv file the following line:

**> `sep=;`**

and you will note that Excel understand your .csv file.

Answer (score 1):

Change your language to English US, it works for me, but separator will be changed to English US as well, of course

Answer (score 0):

Problem was language settings used a ";" instead of a ","! Changed it and magic it works.

Thanks

Comment: Comma doesn't mean the same thing in Europe and the US.  Could that be the reason why the strange setting was in there?

Comment: Yes. See https://hotware.wordpress.com/2009/12/16/trouble-with-opening-csv-files-with-excel-the-comma-and-semicolon-issue-in-excel-due-to-regional-settings-for-europe/ and https://superuser.com/questions/606272/how-to-get-excel-to-interpret-the-comma-as-a-default-delimiter-in-csv-files/606274#606274